# How to use repository or presentation variables in BI publisher?

Tags: oracle, repository, obiee, bi-publisher

We have a report on BIP that shows data based on three parameters. One of these is date parameter. What I want to do is to schedule that report to be sent to emails with date parameter set to last 'working' day of last month. Working day means that  last day of last month may not be last working day of last month since it may be sunday or some holiday.

For this purpose I created repository variable that gets this working day. When I checked this variable in OBIEE it worked fine. However, in BIP, I couldn't use that variable to set default value of the date parameter.

What can I do? Maybe I can set parameter's default value by SQL expression? Or is there any way to use repo variable in BIP?

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't searched on Oracle support yet, you can only use repository variables if you use OBIEE as your data source.

```
syntax: valueof("variable")
```

Comment: I have searched of course,  but couldn't use it because my date source is not OBIEE.  I can't use OBIEE as data source since my tables are not there. No way we can use valueof("variable") for other data sources?

Comment: I think  you have to work around the limitation. You could try building the logic of the last working day in SQL itself. Or, you could lookup from a table/XML/webservice , and pull that into BIP.

Comment: Thank you. I already have SQL script that gets last working day, but I was unable to use it in BIP. Maybe I should call some function from BIP.

Comment: You could setup OBIEE analysis as a datasource for you BIP report and get that variable through that.  https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2008/04/bi-publisher-reports-with-multiple-data-sources/